# difficulty splitting regex into 3 capture groups

Tags: regex

I have the following regex in JavaScript;

`/^([^\s]* > )(.*)/gmi`

and I want it to run on the following text;

> danger > this is some danger notification text

The final result should be 3 captured fields; 'danger', '>', and 'this is some danger notification text'.

As it is right now though, I only get 2.

'danger >' 'this is some danger notification text'.

Is there a way to get the '>' separated from the rest?

Comment: You only have 2 capturing groups. No wonder you have just 2. Try [`/^(\S*)\s*(>)\s*(.*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/kV1xY6/1) - but I do not know why capture a single known `>`.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for help with. It took me a long time to make this regex, I'm not clear how to get another capturing group. I read a lot of documentation to get this far, already! It's really confusing stuff. @.@

Comment: use `^([^\s]*)\s+(>)\s+(.*)`

Comment: The question to ponder upon is why do you need to capture a single known character?

Comment: Also, an idea: `"danger > this is some danger notification text".split(" > ");` and `alert(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(">")).trim() + "\nAND\n" + s.substring(s.indexOf(">") + 1).trim());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
(^\S+)\s+(>)\s+(.*)
```

Now, `\1` is `danger`, `\2` is `>` and `\3` is `this is some danger notification text`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jU3lF3/3)

Comment: Incredible outpouring from you guys. Thank you so much. This worked, and the post from @John Clifford worked. I don't know which one to mark as the right answer!

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked pretty long last night to make the initial site using regex101. I was pretty proud of it until I realized I still had to create another capture group! I can't believe it was so easy to filter out. Is it safe to wrap the second capture group in parenthesis to make it easier to read?

Comment: Ciel: Wrapping a group in parentheses is what *makes* it a capture group. You can use parentheses to make things easier to read, but usually if you do that you should make it a non-capturing group by putting ?: at the beginning i.e. (?:whatever is in here will not be captured)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new capturing group is as simple as putting brackets around what you want to group. In your regex, you're including the > as part of the first capture group, which is why you're not getting it by itself.

Change it to

```
^([^\s]*) (>) (.*)
```

This will capture the first word, the >, and the following text separately.

See https://regex101.com/r/dR5rK5/1 to see the working regex in action.

Comment: Wow. The outpouring from the regex community is completely new to me. You guys are amazing. So much information in such little time. This worked, and the post from @heemayl worked. I don't know which to accept!

Comment: I know Wiktor, but the question wasn't about better ways to write the pattern. I was focusing on the OP's actual question, which was how to get the third capturing group. :P

Comment: Ciel: Honestly I'd accept heemayl's since it's a better way of writing the regex. As I said above, I was focusing on the question you asked rather than how to make a better pattern, but overall heemayl's is the superior answer.

Comment: "Superior"? No explanation at all, that is a junk  answer. Yours is much better.